# Create a curl or some request in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, openssl

create a curl or some request in nodejs that does the same thing that this command does `openssl s_client api-prd.koerich.com.br:443 2> / dev / null | openssl x509 -noout -dates` I am trying to convert a openssl  to a nodeJS or curl, but fail
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const moment = require('moment');
const sslChecker = require('ssl-checker');

const get_domain = 'api-prd.koerich.com.br';
sslChecker(get_domain).then((certdata) => {

    var startdate = new Date(certdata.validFrom);
    var enddate = new Date(certdata.validTo);
    var certstart = moment(startdate);
    var certend = moment(enddate);
    var ssldata = ([{
        domain: get_domain,
        issued: certstart.format('LLLL'),
        expires: certend.format('LLLL'),
        daysleft: certdata.daysRemaining
    }]);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ssldata, null, 4));

}).catch((err) => {
    if (err.code === 'ENOTFOUND') {
        console.log('Fix Hostname or Provide Correct Domain Name');
        res.send(JSON.stringify('false'));
    } else if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
        console.log('Fix Hostname or Provide Correct Domain Name');
        res.send(JSON.stringify('false'));
    }
});
```